# Concerning Samanya Upanishads

Tags: upanishads, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

Have Ramanujacharya , Madhvacharya quoted /cited in their granthaas(works)  from Samanya(minor) Upanishads?Do we have any of their view point on Samanya Upanishads.

Comment: The Mahopanishad is the absolute cornerstone of the Srivaishnavite and Madhwite sects.